# Multiple Getters for Swift Properties?

Tags: swift, getter-setter, computed-properties

Is there any way in Swift 3 to have a class with a computed property that is computationally expensive the first time, but remains constant afterwards, to have separate getters (an initial one, then another for each subsequent request)? i.e.

```
class Example {
    var computationallyIntensive: String? {
        return try? String(contentsOf: unlistedFile, encoding: .utf8)
    }
}
```

I am aware of initializers, however this property needn't be initialized at the creation of the class.

Ideally, the second call would return much sooner than the first:

```
let test = Example()
if test.computationallyIntensive == "base case" {
    print(test.computationallyIntensive)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [*Lazy Stored Property*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html):

```
lazy var computationallyIntensive: String? = computeComputationallyIntensive()

func computeComputationallyIntensive() -> String?  {
    return try? String(contentsOf: unlistedFile, encoding: .utf8)
}
```

The call to `computeComputationallyIntensive`, if any, will happen during the first call to `computationallyIntensive`.

Comment: Is there any way to add a setter to a lazy var? In other words, do lazy vars work with computed properties?

Comment: @BrandonBradley My understanding is that lazy properties must be computed, so they do not allow setters.